# How long is an ssl session key valid? And how is it associated with a client?

Tags: session, ssl

From what I understand SSL uses asymmetric cryptography to securely exchange a session key generated by the client, which is then used for symmetric encryption. I have a few questions on this

- How long is this session key valid?
- How does the server keep track of which session key is valid for which client? Does the server keep track of this by the client's ip address? (That is session key "A" belongs to client xx.xxx.xx.xx) If yes, couldn't my ip address be same as other people who use the same isp and live in my vicinity?
- Does the server instead use both ip address and port number to keep track of the
  client? If so, wouldn't the port number change for every HTTP/HTTPS
  request? Which would mean that the session key cannot be mapped back to the client anymore.

Answer (score 1):

> From what I understand SSL uses asymmetric cryptography to securely exchange a session key generated by the client, which is then used for symmetric encryption.

No, you don't understand. The session key is derived independently at both ends. It is never transmitted.

> - How long is this session key valid?

As long as a piece of string. It is valid until a re-handshake is performed, which can be initiated by either peer at any time.

> - How does the server keep track of which session key is valid for which client?

In the SSL Session.

> Does the server keep track of this by the client's ip address?

No, by the session ID which is negotiated during the handshake.

> (That is session key "A" belongs to client xx.xxx.xx.xx) If yes, couldn't my ip address be same as other people who use the same isp and live in my vicinity?

No. They thought of that, surprisingly enough.

> Does the server instead use both ip address and port number to keep track of the
>      client?

No, it uses the SSL session, and also the HTTP session in the case of Web servers.

> If so, wouldn't the port number change for every HTTP/HTTPS
>      request?

Yes, which is why they don't use it. They thought about that too.

> Which would mean that the session key cannot be mapped back to the client anymore.

Which is why they don't do it. You've just invented yet another obvious vulnerability that would be obviously stupid to implement. You can stop now. They really did think about all this stuff.

Comment: "No. They thought of that, surprisingly enough."  Yeah, I thought I was the only one in the universe who thought of that. Thanks for setting that straight.

Comment: I believe we generate a session key right after the SSL handshake is done, right? If so, then the user might have not been logged-in yet. My question is would the session key that is previously created after the handshake remain the same after the user is logged-in? (Pretty much like usually having a two distinct session id's per pre and post login)